# Compile library with autotools and an additional compiler flag

Tags: c++, makefile, gdal

I'm building library `gdal-1.9.2`. After launching the `./configure` command, `make` fails with the error

> ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]

If I launch the last failed command in a console  with the additional option `-fpermissive`, it finishes successfully (with a warning, not an error).

```
g++ -g -O2 -Wall -DOGR_ENABLED -I/home/unona/unona-pult/gdal-1.9.2/port -DHAVE_LIBZ -fpermissive -c cplkeywordparser.cpp  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/cplkeywordparser.o
```

How to finish the build process now? Just `make` rebuilds it and crashes in the same way.

Comment: @lubgr thank you a lot for fast and correct help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For autotools builds, you can expect the `./configure` script to check for compiler flags set via environment variables (command line options are usually supported as well, but they are not as easy to memorize, IMHO). The names for these variables are standard ones, and in your case, it should be

```
CXXFLAGS="-fpermissive" ./configure

make install
```

The configure script generates the `makefile` such that the value of `CXXFLAGS` is passed to the compiler while building.